How to disable secondary display overlay without disabling it?
I am using scrcpy to create a secondary display for streaming it to my PC.
I have used the following adb shell commands (with help from GitHub comments):
Create a secondary display: settings put global overlay_display_devices "1920x1080/200"
Get the display id: dumpsys display | grep -E 'Display [0-9]{1,2}'
Start scrcpy: scrcpy --display-id 21
Then I start a launcher activity in that display (I have installed a desktop-style launcher from the Play Store):
adb shell am start -S -n com.protheme.launcher.winx2.launcher/com.centsol.w10launcher.activity.SplashActivity --display 21
With these steps, I have successfully started a launcher in the secondary display and launched apps in it separate from the primary display.
But what hinders me from getting a true multi-display experience is the fact that the primary display shows an overlay of the secondary display.
Secondary display:

Primary display:

So my question is, how to disable the overlay but keep the secondary display enabled? So far I have browsed several questions, but the solution was to disable the secondary display entirely.
